# Migrating from TeamForge To CloudForge

Tags: svn, repository, collabnet, teamforge

We are using TeamForge for our svn repos. We realized that we could save by moving to CloudForge. What would be your recommended approach to moving from TeamForge to CloudForge.

Are there any automated tools to move from one to the other?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will just have to take a dump of the repositories from /svnroot of your Teamforge Server.
2. Zip it
3. Login to Cloudforge as Admin.
4. On the Project page > SVN > Import Repository.
5. Next, select the zipped dump file from your computer, and select 'Begin Upload.

You can automate the archiving process by constructing a script, but the import has to be done manually.

Documentation: [Click here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160906013404/https://help.cloudforge.com/entries/22309267-Importing-an-Existing-Repository-into-CloudForge-Subversion)